# SEARCH PHP MYSQL QUERY

Tags: php, search

I am trying to make a search program. I have three tables: `postivewords`, `negativewords` and `recommendationwords`. These tables consist only of word_id then the word. How I do it in a query? This is what I have so far. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
if(isset($_POST['searchword']))    
{        
    $word = $_POST['search'];            
    $search1= mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM positivethesaurus where word like '%$word%'"));
    $search2= mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM negativethesaurus where word like '%$word%'"));    
    $search3= mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recommendationthesaurus where word like '%$word%'"));
}
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from negativethesaurus, positivethesaurus,recomendationthesaurus where negativethesaurus.word like '%"word%' or positivethesaurus.word like '%word%' or recomendationthesaurus.word like '%word%';
```

This may be not the fastest way (you would use indexes and freetext) but it will be down on only one query.

Oh yes, that been said this query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: #1052 - Column 'word' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: echo "<form action='#' method='post'>";
      echo "Search word here: <input type='text' name='search'>";

echo "<input type='submit' name='searchword' value='Search'>";

echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST['searchword']))
{
$word = $_POST['search'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM positivethesaurus where word like '%$word%'");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
 echo $row['word']."<br>";

}

}

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = SELECT positivethesaurus .*,negativethesaurus.*,recommendationthesaurus.*   FROM positivethesaurus,negativethesaurus,recommendationthesaurus where positivethesaurus.word like '%$word%' OR negativethesaurus.word like '%$word%' OR recommendationthesaurus.word like '%$word%'";
```

**UPDATES**
if you want to check if results not found then do it like this

```
<?php
 $query = mysql_query("Your Query Here");
 $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($rowCount>0) {
   // DO YOur STUFF IF RESULTS FOUND
 } else {
  echo "No Results Found";
 }
?>
```

**Please not that mysql_* function should not be used**

Hope this works. Not Tested though. Let me know if you find any problem

Comment: i wanna do a validation for this one.. where if the word does not exist?? it will echo word not found? how do i do this in a while loop?      echo "<form action='#' method='post'>";
echo "Search word here: <input type='text' name='search'>";

echo "<input type='submit' name='searchword' value='Search'>";

echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST['searchword']))
{
$word = $_POST['search'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM positivethesaurus where word like '%$word%'");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
 echo $row['word']."<br>";

}

}

Answer (score 0):

also do mysql_escape_string to avoid sql injection

```
  $word = $_POST['search'];
  $word = mysql_escape_string($word);
```

Comment: what does the mysql escape do again? :/

Answer (score -1):

1) Select the respected column instead of select * from
2) avoid sql injection

Comment: Sql injection is not something you want to use. It's something you want to avoid being used against you.